# Tagging software that is friendly to moving to another computer

Tags: file-management

I've been looking to start adding tags to my images, but soon realised gif and png don't support that. So I started looking for third-party software; however as expected it saves information on tags in its own database rather than on the file. That means that if I move the files to another computer the information is lost; unless I manually copy the database and make sure I move them to the same folder or some other pain in the ass like that. Is there (free) tagging software that is made to be friendly to that kind of thing? I'm on Windows.

Comment: The common portable way to add tags and other meta data to files is creating a separate file that has the same name, just a different extension. Check out e.g. the XMP file format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform

Comment: You need to use a format that support EXIF or similar and then you can use the exiftool to embed your data directly inside the picture.  filetype PNG version 1.2 added support for EXIF back in 2017.  However, GIF never added support that I know of so your stuck with XMP files for that.

Comment: Adding XMP files with the same name to keep the metadata sounds nice; but is there a program that makes the process easier?